# DerivativeCheck fails with minFunc

Tags: matlab, optimization, neural-networks

I'm trying to train a single layer of an autoencoder using minFunc, and while the cost function appears to decrease, when enabled, the DerivativeCheck fails. The code I'm using is  as close to textbook values as possible, though extremely simplified.

The loss function I'm using is the squared-error:

$ J(W; x) = \frac{1}{2}||a^{l} - x||^2 $

with $a^{l}$ equal to $\sigma(W^{T}x)$, where $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function. The gradient should therefore be:

$ \delta = (a^{l} - x)*a^{l}(1 - a^{l}) $

$ \nabla_{W} = \delta(a^{l-1})^T $

Note, that to simplify things, I've left off the bias altogether. While this will cause poor performance, it shouldn't affect the gradient check, as I'm only looking at the weight matrix. Additionally, I've tied the encoder and decoder matrices, so there is effectively a single weight matrix.

The code I'm using for the loss function is (**edit:** I've vectorized the loop I had and cleaned the code up a little):

```
% loss function passed to minFunc
function [ loss, grad ] = calcLoss(theta, X, nHidden)
  [nInstances, nVars] = size(X);

  % we get the variables a single vector, so need to roll it into a weight matrix
  W = reshape(theta(1:nVars*nHidden), nVars, nHidden);
  Wp = W; % tied weight matrix

  % encode each example (nInstances)
  hidden = sigmoid(X*W);

  % decode each sample (nInstances)
  output = sigmoid(hidden*Wp);

  % loss function: sum(-0.5.*(x - output).^2)
  % derivative of loss: -(x - output)*f'(o)
  % if f is sigmoid, then f'(o) = output.*(1-output)
  diff = X - output;
  error = -diff .* output .* (1 - output);
  dW = hidden*error';

  loss = 0.5*sum(diff(:).^2, 2) ./ nInstances;

  % need to unroll gradient matrix back into a single vector
  grad = dW(:) ./ nInstances;
end
```

Below is the code I use to run the optimizer (for a single time, as the runtime is fairly long with all training samples):

```
examples = 5000;
fprintf('loading data..\n');
images = readMNIST('train-images-idx3-ubyte', examples) / 255.0;

data = images(:, :, 1:examples);

% each row is a different training sample
X = reshape(data, examples, 784);

% initialize weight matrix with random values
% W: (R^{784} -> R^{10}), W': (R^{10} -> R^{784})
numHidden = 10; % NOTE: this is extremely small to speed up DerivativeCheck
numVisible = 784;
low = -4*sqrt(6./(numHidden + numVisible));
high = 4*sqrt(6./(numHidden + numVisible));
W = low + (high-low)*rand(numVisible, numHidden);

% run optimization
options = {};
options.Display = 'iter';
options.GradObj = 'on';
options.MaxIter = 10;
mfopts.MaxFunEvals = ceil(options.MaxIter * 2.5);
options.DerivativeCheck = 'on';
options.Method = 'lbfgs';    
[ x, f, exitFlag, output] = minFunc(@calcLoss, W(:), options, X, numHidden);
```

The results I get with the DerivitiveCheck on are generally less than 0, but greater than 0.1. I've tried similar code using batch gradient descent, and get slightly better results (some are < 0.0001, but certainly not all).

I'm not sure if I made either a mistake with my math or code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**update**

I discovered a small typo in my code (which doesn't appear in the code below) causing exceptionally bad performance. Unfortunately, I'm still getting getting less-than-good results. For example, comparison between the two gradients:

```
calculate     check
0.0379        0.0383
0.0413        0.0409
0.0339        0.0342
0.0281        0.0282
0.0322        0.0320
```

with differences of up to 0.04, which I'm assuming is still failing.

Comment: I think it is weird to use squared error and sigmoidal outputs. Where did you get the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I might have solved the problem. Generally the differences in the gradients are < 1e-4, though I do have at least one which is 6e-4. Does anyone know if this is still acceptable?

To get this result, I rewrote the code and without tying the weight matrices (I'm not sure if doing so will always cause the derivative check to fail). I've also included biases, as they didn't complicate things too badly.

Something else I realized when debugging is that it's *really* easy to make a mistake in the code. For example, it took me a while to catch:

```
grad_W1 = error_h*X';
```

instead of:

```
grad_W1  = X*error_h';
```

While the difference between these two lines is just the transpose of grad_W1, because of the requirement of packing/unpacking the parameters into a single vector, there's no way for Matlab to complain about grad_W1 being the wrong dimensions.

I've also included my own derivative check which gives slightly different answers than minFunc's (my deriviate check gives differences that are all below 1e-4).

**fwdprop.m:**

```
function [ hidden, output ] = fwdprop(W1, bias1, W2, bias2, X)
  hidden = sigmoid(bsxfun(@plus, W1'*X, bias1));
  output = sigmoid(bsxfun(@plus, W2'*hidden, bias2));
 end
```

**calcLoss.m:**

```
function [ loss, grad ] = calcLoss(theta, X, nHidden)
  [nVars, nInstances] = size(X);
  [W1, bias1, W2, bias2] = unpackParams(theta, nVars, nHidden);
  [hidden, output] = fwdprop(W1, bias1, W2, bias2, X);
  err = output - X;
  delta_o = err .* output .* (1.0 - output);
  delta_h = W2*delta_o .* hidden .* (1.0 - hidden);

  grad_W1 = X*delta_h';
  grad_bias1 = sum(delta_h, 2);
  grad_W2 = hidden*delta_o';
  grad_bias2 = sum(delta_o, 2);

  loss = 0.5*sum(err(:).^2);
  grad = packParams(grad_W1, grad_bias1, grad_W2, grad_bias2);
end
```

**unpackParams.m:**

```
function [ W1, bias1, W2, bias2 ] = unpackParams(params, nVisible, nHidden)
  mSize = nVisible*nHidden;

  W1 = reshape(params(1:mSize), nVisible, nHidden);
  offset = mSize;    

  bias1 = params(offset+1:offset+nHidden);
  offset = offset + nHidden;

  W2 = reshape(params(offset+1:offset+mSize), nHidden, nVisible);
  offset = offset + mSize;

  bias2 = params(offset+1:end);
end
```

**packParams.m**

```
function [ params ] = packParams(W1, bias1, W2, bias2)
  params = [W1(:); bias1; W2(:); bias2(:)];
end
```

**checkDeriv.m:**

```
function [check] = checkDeriv(X, theta, nHidden, epsilon)
  [nVars, nInstances] = size(X);

  [W1, bias1, W2, bias2] = unpackParams(theta, nVars, nHidden);
  [hidden, output] = fwdprop(W1, bias1, W2, bias2, X);
  err = output - X;
  delta_o = err .* output .* (1.0 - output);
  delta_h = W2*delta_o .* hidden .* (1.0 - hidden);

  grad_W1 = X*delta_h';
  grad_bias1 = sum(delta_h, 2);
  grad_W2 = hidden*delta_o';
  grad_bias2 = sum(delta_o, 2);

  check = zeros(size(theta, 1), 2);
  grad = packParams(grad_W1, grad_bias1, grad_W2, grad_bias2);
  for i = 1:size(theta, 1)
      Jplus = calcHalfDeriv(X, theta(:), i, nHidden, epsilon);
      Jminus = calcHalfDeriv(X, theta(:), i, nHidden, -epsilon);

      calcGrad = (Jplus - Jminus)/(2*epsilon);
      check(i, :) = [calcGrad grad(i)];
  end
end
```

**checkHalfDeriv.m:**

```
function [ loss ] = calcHalfDeriv(X, theta, i, nHidden, epsilon)
  theta(i) = theta(i) + epsilon;

  [nVisible, nInstances] = size(X);
  [W1, bias1, W2, bias2] = unpackParams(theta, nVisible, nHidden);
  [hidden, output] = fwdprop(W1, bias1, W2, bias2, X);

  err = output - X;
  loss = 0.5*sum(err(:).^2);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt, you write that the loss should be

```
% loss function: sum(-0.5.*(x - output).^2)
```

This is wrong because of the minus: you want the loss to be big if `x` and `output` differ a lot. While you code the loss correctly, you don't code the derivative of it correctly:

```
error = -diff .* output .* (1 - output);
```

The minus in front of `diff` has to go.